# Concatenate XML Node data

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have XML look like this

```
<BoxResult>
<DocumentType>BCN</DocumentType>
<DocumentID>BCN_20131113_1197005001#854@11XEZPADAHANDELC</DocumentID>
<DocumentVersion>1</DocumentVersion>
<ebXMLMessageId>CENTRAL_MATCHING</ebXMLMessageId>
<State>FAILED</State>
<Timestamp>2013-11-13T13:02:57</Timestamp>
<Reason>
    <ReasonCode>efet:IDNotFound</ReasonCode>
    <ReasonText>Unknown Sender</ReasonText>
</Reason>
<Reason>
    <ReasonCode>efet:IDNotFound</ReasonCode>
    <ReasonText>Unknown Receiver</ReasonText>
</Reason>
</BoxResult>
```

In my C# code , i need to parse through the XML and concatenate the Reason Text Data.

Basically , i need the output as **Unknown Sender ; Unknown Receiver**

I tried the following code but i am not getting the desired output

```
XmlNodeList ReasonNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(/BoxResult/Reason);              
foreach (XmlNode xmln in ReasonNodeList)
{
     ReasonText = ReasonText + ";" + xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(/BoxResult/Reason/ReasonText).InnerXml.ToString();
}
if (ReasonText != " ")
{
     ReasonText = ReasonText.Substring(1);
}
```

The output i am getting from this code is **Unknown Sender ; Unknown Sender**

It is not displaying Unknown Receiver

Please advise and your help will be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always using the same node to retrieve the data. The `xmlDoc` is always called (i.e. the first `<Reason>` node), instead of each targeted node.

```
XmlNodeList ReasonNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/BoxResult/Reason/ReasonText");  //change here            
foreach (XmlNode xmln in ReasonNodeList)
{
     ReasonText = ReasonText + ";" + xmln.InnerXml.ToString(); //change here
}
if (ReasonText != " ")
{
     ReasonText = ReasonText.Substring(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei V . I need the value of only ReasonText tag .

Comment: @VikasKunte, I updated the xPath too. Don't forget the quotes around it.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating through `<Reason>` nodes and each time selecting the first `/BoxResult/Reason/ReasonText` node in document (note you're not using your `xmln` variable anywhere).

By the way, here's a shorter version (replaces your whole code block):

```
ReasonText += String.Join(";",
                          xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/BoxResult/Reason/ReasonText")
                                .Cast<XmlNode>()
                                .Select(n => n.InnerText));
```